# Why JS animation is stuck?

Tags: javascript

I want the box to traverse the inside of the container from left to right, then down, then right to left and finally back up to the original position. The examples I found all include extra array pos = [180,180]. I don't understand why do I need it when my IF conditions seem to cover all positions.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var t = setInterval(slide, 5);
  pos1 = [0, 0];
  var box = document.getElementById('sqr');

  function slide() {
    if (pos1[0] < 180 && pos1[1] < 180) {
      pos1[0]++;
      box.style.left = pos1[0] + "px";
    } else if (pos1[0] >= 180 && pos1[1] < 180) {
      pos1[1]++;
      box.style.top = pos1[1] + "px";
    } else if (pos1[0] >= 180 && pos1[1] >= 180) {
      pos1[0]--;
      box.style.left = pos1[0] + "px";
    } else if (pos1[0] <= 0 && pos1[1] >= 180) {
      pos1[1]--;
      box.style.top = pos1[1] + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#contain {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}

#sqr {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="contain">
  <div id="sqr"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because based on your logic, once you hit 180 you begin to subtract. After you take away 1, you have 179, but instead of continuing to subtract so you end up at zero, your loop begins to increment again and you get stuck. Console log your `pos1[0]` and `pos1[1]` variables in your function so you can watch them change.

Comment: It's not the problem (it could easily be the *next* problem), but: That code is falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*. Declare your variables in the appropriate scope. Not declaring them, in loose mode, makes them globals. In this case, you probably just need `var` in front of `pos`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because, when animation gets to `pos1 = [180, 180]`, it executes:

```
else if (pos1[0] >= 180 && pos1[1] >= 180) {
  pos1[0]--;
  box.style.left = pos1[0] + "px";
}
```

And then `pos1 = [179, 180]`, which is not covered by the code.

I suggest using something like that:

```
var direction = 0; //0 - right, 1 - down, 2 - left, 3 - up

function slide() {
  if (pos1[0] < 180 && pos1[1] = 0) {
    direction = 0;
  } else if (pos1[0] = 180 && pos1[1] < 180) {
    direction = 1;
  } else if (pos1[0] > 0 && pos1[1] = 180) {
    direction = 2;
  } else if (pos1[0] = 0 && pos1[1] > 0) {
    direction = 3;
  }
  switch(direction){
    case 0:
      pos1[0]++;
      break;
    case 1:
      pos1[1]++;
      break;
    case 2:
      pos1[0]--;
      break;
    case 3:
      pos1[1]--;
      break;
  }
  box.style.left = pos1[0] + "px";
  box.style.top = pos1[1] + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Once the box gets to the maximum X and Y positions, the program is still checking to make sure the box hasn't reached the maximum yet, which causes the all IF conditions to fail. You could do it by checking for Y=0 for the first "leg", X=MAX for the next, Y=MAX for the next, and then X=0 for the last, but instead of that, you can set a "state" which has 4 values to determine which "leg" of the animation is being run, and then just run it for 180 iterations each.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var t = setInterval(slide, 5);
  pos1 = [0, 0];
  var box = document.getElementById('sqr');
  state = 0;
  iterations = 0;

  function slide() {
    if (iterations >= 180) {state = (state + 1) % 4; iterations = 0;}
    if (state === 0) pos1[0]++;
    else if (state == 1) pos1[1]++;
    else if (state == 2) pos1[0]--;
    else if (state == 3) pos1[1]--;
    iterations++;
    box.style.left = pos1[0] + "px";
    box.style.top  = pos1[1] + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
#contain {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}

#sqr {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="contain">
  <div id="sqr"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: not good that you create global variable, but the solution is nice

Comment: @dfsq I can change that, but this is something that works. I will fix that when I get around to it in a bit maybe.

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var t = setInterval(slide, 5);

  var box = document.getElementById('sqr');
  var left = 0,
    top = 0;

  function slide() {
    var pos1 = [parseInt(box.style.left || 0), parseInt(box.style.top || 0)]

    console.log(pos1);
    if (pos1[0] == 0 && pos1[1] == 0) { //Top left, go right
      left = 1;
      top = 0;
    } else if (pos1[0] == 180 && pos1[1] == 0) { //Top right, go down
      left = 0;
      top = 1;
    } else if (pos1[0] == 180 && pos1[1] == 180) { //Bottom right, go left
      left = -1;
      top = 0;
    } else if (pos1[0] == 0 && pos1[1] == 180) { //Bottom left, go up
      left = 0;
      top = -1;
    }
    box.style.left = (parseInt(box.style.left || 0) + left) + "px";
    box.style.top = (parseInt(box.style.top || 0) + top) + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
#contain {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}

#sqr {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="contain">
  <div id="sqr"></div>
</div>
```

Here's my take on it. React according to the position of the element, when it reaches a corner, change directions. This makes things easier, since we do not rely on actual positions to know where to go next step...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not usually a fan of doing someone's homework for them, but I got intrigued as to what would make it work and couldn't help myself. *shrugs*

The `if` statements have been tailored to be more explicit with what they need. This of course was achieved by following the methods suggested to you by @j08691, by just adding a `console.log(pos1);` at the top of each `if` section.

This is just for reference, in fact, @Salketer has managed to post before me and it looks a lot cleaner than this. The real *answer* is in the comments by @j08691

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var t = setInterval(slide, 5),
      pos1 = [0, 0],
      box = document.getElementById('sqr');

  function slide() {
    if (pos1[0] < 180 && pos1[1] === 0) {
      console.log(pos1);
      pos1[0]++;
      box.style.left = pos1[0] + "px";
    } else if (pos1[0] === 180 && pos1[1] < 180) {
      console.log(pos1);
      pos1[1]++;
      box.style.top = pos1[1] + "px";
    } else if ((pos1[0] <= 180 && pos1[0] >= 1) && pos1[1] === 180) {
      console.log(pos1);
      pos1[0]--;
      box.style.left = pos1[0] + "px";
    } else if (pos1[0] === 0 && pos1[1] <= 180) {
      console.log(pos1);
      pos1[1]--;
      box.style.top = pos1[1] + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#contain {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}

#sqr {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="contain">
  <div id="sqr"></div>
</div>
```